# How to upload images to ftp server?

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, ftp

I'm using database to store my image files. As it's pretty slow I wanted to save them onto ftp server.

I tried `move__uploaded_file()` but it seems to nor work for me (it does not show any error, but file is not saved nor moved).

```
$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$location = "/images/images_doprava/";

if($size <= 2621440) {
    if(!move_uploaded_file($temp,$location.$name)) { 
        echo "Error!"; 
    }
    header( 'Location: ../edit.php' );
} else {
    echo "Image has size bigger than 2,5 MB";
}
```

So, how can I upload the files onto ftp server and get the name of saved file? Thank you.

Comment: Let's break the problem into smaller pieces. 1) can you upload any files at all (using simpler code)? Does php have write permissions in the target directory? and 2) are you able to do anything with your database?

Comment: Your comments refer to an FTP server, but your script (if it works) would handle an HTTP upload. These are not the same. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FTP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php) maybe a good option

```
<?php
    $Name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $Temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $Type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $Size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $Location = "/images/images_doprava/";
    // if(($Type == image/jpeg) || ($Type == image/jpg) || ($Type == image/gif) || ($Type == image/png) || ($Type == image/pjpeg))
    //  {
            if($Size <= 2621440)
                {
                    //move_uploaded_file($Temp,$Location.$Name);
    $fp = fopen($Temp, 'r');
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

    // login with username and password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    // try to upload $file
    if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
        echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n";
    } else {
        echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
    }
                   /*if(!move_uploaded_file($Temp,$Location.$Name))
                      { 
                                             echo "Error!"; 
                                          }
                    header( 'Location: ../edit.php' );
                }*/
    else
    {
         echo "Image has size more than 2,5 MB";
    }
    //  }
    //else 
    //  {
    //      echo "Format is not supported!";
    //  }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with this library: http://www.plupload.com/
they have very well documented examples for javascript (reduce image size before you upload image) and php code (write file to server directory)